# electron with nodejs and angular

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

I am trying to set up  **Angular 5** project in **Electron** and also run **nodejs** in server side, i know that electron permit to create desktop app, but is it possible to create server side app with electron, also i'm not sure if it's possible to have the nodejs app and angular all in the same project with **ngx electron**.

Comment: electron app will be your front-end. you have to create a separate server for this.

Comment: can't put nodejs code in electron???

Comment: no, put the server separate

Comment: i think this an example when using nodeJS in electron, could you verufy please

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want a desktop application that in some way also communicates with a server.

Sure, that's possible since Electron will bundle [node.js in the generated binary](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules).

The easiest way I can think of is setting up an HTTP API (e.G [REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)) on your server side (possible with any language, I'd recommend either PHP or Node.js) and use [`http`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer) in your ng/electron app to talk to the server.

```
http.get(options, (res) => {
  // Do stuff
}).on('socket', (socket) => {
  socket.emit('agentRemove');
});
```

Comment: i want a project which contains Angular, electron and nodejs in the same project 
some told me that we can't use electron in server side, am i obliged  to run nodejs in a server separately of the angularApp
can u please look if ngx-electron can do the work,

Comment: Even if it doesn't have the apis, as long as you have electron, you can just use [native node modules](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/using-native-node-modules)

Comment: @KanekiEm why do you need angular and electron on a server? After compiling, you will have a binary like .exe for windows. You can run that binary on your server but I don't see the point. Just build a website.

Comment: we have to do a app for a weight indicator, so nodejs take data from the weight indicator, and angular 5  to enter additionnal data, and electron for creating desktop app, so we want to make all this in one application but i don't knwo if it's possible

Comment: How do you collect the data from the scale and can you describe what exactly the server and what the app should do? Can you update your question?